# Flutter How to check connection TCP IP

Tags: flutter, dart, sockets, tcp, listener

I want to perform an operation, but before that I want to check the connection status to the server whether it is still connected or not. If it is connected then perform the operation, if not then reconnect.

here is my code on button on pressed

```
Future<void> masuk() async {
    if (_socketConnection == null) {
      setState(() {
        connect();
      });
    } else if (_subscription == null) {
      setState(() {
        connect();
      });
    } else {
      _getId().then((id) {
        setState(() {
          deviceId = id;
          print("Sambungan Masih terhubung");
          send();
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

and here is code for connection

```
Future<void> connect() async {
    var server = "10.0.2.2";
    int port = 8000;
    if (server.isNotEmpty) {
      SocketClient socketClient = SocketClient(server, port);
      _subscription = socketClient.connect().doOnCancel(() {
        setState(() {
          _subscription = null;
          _socketConnection = null;
        });
      }).listen((connection) async {
        print("listen:$connection");
        setState(() {
          _socketConnection = connection;
        });
      }, onError: (error) {
        _result = "Connect Error:$error";
        _subscription?.cancel();
        setState(() {
          _subscription = null;
          _socketConnection = null;
        });
      }, cancelOnError: true);
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
```

I have to restart the application first if I want to reconnect if the condition is "The server is off or restarted"